# How can I ensure that /tmp directory is encrypted, too, but not the whole file system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

I installed Linux Mint and at the beginning set the option to have the whole file system encrypted. The reason for this was that I want to have extended privacy in case the disk of that computer gets in the wrong hands.

I realized that encrypting the whole file system has a big disadvantage: I cannot log into that machine anymore remotely after a power loss etc.

Therefore I want to set up the system again, but this time only encrypting the home directory of the user but not encrypting the whole file system.

I know that a lot of files are temporarily stored / created in the /tmp directory.

**How can I ensure that also the /tmp directory is encrypted when I set up the system again?**

Ideas I can think of are:

- moving the /tmp directory as a sub-directory of the /home folder (but I assume that also processes not related to my own user will use the /tmp folder, too, so that this is not a good idea).
- somehow encrypting the /tmp folder... . But how can the system start independently from any password input and still use that /tmp folder?

Comment: It's still possible to unlock an encrypted root disk remotely [using an SSH server in the initramfs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/security/how-to-unlock-luks-using-dropbear-ssh-keys-remotely-in-linux/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is /tmp (which is explicitly for ephemeral data), you have some really good options.  You can encrypt the pants off of it, and you never need to persist the encryption key beyond a reboot.

First, simplest, and fastest:  Encrypted swap, plus tmpfs.  All of the benefits of encryption, plus the computer uses RAM for /tmp when possible / when that makes sense.

More complicated options include:  Omit the tmp partition from the fstab (file-system table; it is a file provided to the OS to indicate how to mount filesystems), and have a startup script that will overwrite the designated partition with an encrypted partition using a random (generated) key, mount it, then throw away the key.